# Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host

Tags: java, jboss

I want to test my webserviceRest with a junit.
I have made a client with Resteasy and when I start my server I have this error message :

Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./webserviceTest: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./webserviceTest: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003940: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)

Here is my dependencies :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.23.Final</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-moxy</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.23.Final</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>



<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.28</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
  <version>2.28</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

If somebody can help me ??

thanks,

Bulbi.

Comment: As a complete guess I'd say there is an issue with trying to use RESTEasy and Jersey together. We'd really need to see the full stack trace though.